# Can option bytes be used to permanently store user data in the internal flash memory of a STM32 microcontroller?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, low-level, stm32f1

I'm using a STM32F103C8 microcontroller. According to the [STM32F10xxx flash memory programming manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/programming_manual/cd00283419-stm32f10xxx-flash-memory-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf) (p.20) there are 2 option bytes which can be used to store user data. These bytes are called *Data0* and *Data1* and they are stored at address 0x1FFF F804.

Can these 2 bytes be used for permanently and reliably storing information (e.g. the power state of the microcontroller) after the power supply of the microcontroller has been cut off?

Comment: They are read-only so.... it would be pointless if they would reset...

Comment: Nobody knows anything different to what the manual you linked to states. What is unclear to you?  What do you mean by the "power state of the microcontroller"?

Comment: I just wasn't sure if it is reliable to use them for the purpose of storing information permanently. By the "power state of the microcontroller" i mean the information that the microcontroller has been shut down or started up properly. So, during each startup and shutdown this information should be written to the option bytes.

Answer (score 0):

> Can these 2 bytes be used for permanently and reliably storing information (e.g. the power state of the microcontroller) after the power supply of the microcontroller has been cut off?

Yes, just like flash.